# Java Exception : java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: java, exception

So for my Ap computer Science class One of my project keep getting `java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`: 390000 Its a Sound reverse file

Here is the code:

```
import sounds.APSoundClip;
import sounds.Sample;

public class ReverseSound {   

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        APSoundClip clip = new APSoundClip("money.wav");
        APSoundClip newClip = clip.clone();
        int pos = clip.getLength();
        int cloned = 0;

        for(Sample clipSample : clip) {  
            clip.getSample(pos); //error is here
            int newValue = clipSample.getValue();
            newClip.getSample(cloned).setValue(newValue);
            pos--;
            cloned++;
        }
        newClip.draw();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the stack trace?

Comment: Well, it looks like `APSoundClip` is one of your classes ... can you add it's code? Or, if it is too long, the fields, constructor and the `getSample` method?

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a "traditional" mistake - you initialize `pos` with `int pos = clip.getLength();`

Then at the first iteration you do `clip.getSample(pos);` - the last element is at index `clip.getLength() - 1`. You are trying to access the element at position `clip.getLength()`, that's why you are getting the index out of bounds error.

Comment: Exactly, Arrays in java starts from zero. So last element would be array[array.length-1].

Answer (score 0):

Java Arrays start with an index of zero, and because of this, their last index will be one less than their length. In your situation, you are assuming that `clip.getLength()`is the last element in the array, however, when you take a look at the anatomy of the array, it would really be `clip.getLength()-1`.